# CSS Height change from set value to dynamic on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

Im trying to change the the height of my container from 527px (Which is the height of the background for the desktop) to make the background image hidden and make background color stretch to the bottom of the div when on mobile. The clearfix is handled from bootstrap. There are several floated divs inside of my .partbackdrop class that are not show because they are too long. No matter what I change the #PartCarContainer on the @media, besides setting it to a fixed value, it will not adjust accordingly and stretch the background to the div.

**Link Removed. Problem Solved. Setting height to auto for all the divs inside the container.**

CSS

```
#PartCarContainer { background-color: #FFFFFF; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25); box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25); border-radius: 3px; overflow: visible; }
.partbackdrop { background-image: url(../../_common/img/backdrop.jpg); background-position: top center; height: 527px; }

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
#PartCarContainer { height: auto; }
.partbackdrop { background-image: none; }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="PartCarContainer">
<div class="partbackdrop">
    Content
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: It may be a floating problem because of the floats for the page.
I also believe the footer may be suffering from the same problem. If you shrink the window down to below 767px you will see the red background which is my problem.

Comment: I think you will want to remove div.clearfix and add the cleafix class to div#PartCarContainer.

Comment: i have tried this and changed nothing.

Comment: Yes i think so. The only thing i can think of then is maybe i have a float problem somewhere else on the page. So i have included a link in my original post to the page im talking about. If you shrink the window size you will see my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `height:auto` on `.partbackdrop` and on `.partDivMain`

```
.partbackdrop, .partDivMain { height:auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the problem. I appreciate the help.